# How to Add Specific Cell in Excel document using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

This is my scenario, I have a path that contains all excel files. Now, I want to implement a solution that will insert the current "Filename" in specific cell for that file.

For Example:

```
sample.xls
Sample2.xls
Sample3.xls
```

Inside that sample.xls, I want to inset the filename "sample" without the extension on cell "E7" and "E8" then save this file.

I currently have this formula to get the filename without the extension:

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),SEARCH("[",CELL("filename",A1))+1,SEARCH(".",CELL("filename",A1))-1-SEARCH("[",CELL("filename",A1)))
```

Comment: Is it correct that you have the full path in there? And if you can already get the name without the extension, what exactly do you want to do with it after? (PS: you're missing an "r" in "I want to INSET the filename")

Comment: @Kathara Since I have a lists of excel file, I want to implement this in macro. I already tried pasting this formula in a cell and it works fine.

Comment: ok, you know that you can add formulas to cells by vba? Then you can make your cell-range dynamic, for example working with .offset.

Comment: @Kathara Im new with the VBA. Im trying to implement a script that can insert the filename in a defined cell without extension

Comment: on Stackoverflow normally noone will just give you the answer to your problem, you have to show, what you have already tried, the more the better. I'm quite new to vba as well. Have you tried ANYTHING in vba yet?

Comment: In which column do you have the full path normally? in which column do you want the name of the file? in which column do you want the extension? Is it always the same on each list?

Comment: @Kathara I've already try this code

Sub Place1()
    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = ThisWorkbook.Name
    FileName1 = Replace(FileName, ".xls", "")
    Range("BL2:BL3").Value = FileName1
End Sub

Now, i want all excel files located in a path to perform this then save

Comment: Found a link for looping through a folder, you'll have to adapt it of course: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few codes that might help you on the way:

For the last row in a workbook:

```
LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
```

ActiveWorkbook can be replaced by "Workbooks(NameofWorkbook)".

ActiveWorksheet can be replaced by "Sheets(NameofSheet)".

For adding the paths of the excel files to column a:

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
    file = Dir("c:\testfolder\")

    While (file <> "")
       ActiveWorkbook.ActiveWorksheet.Cells((LastRow+1), 1).Value = file
    Wend
    file = Dir
End Sub
```

Not too sure this works, you'll have to test it.

****EDIT_1****

For the file extensions the following might be useful (found on another question):

```
FileExtStr = "." & LCase(Right(wb.Name, Len(wb.Name) - InStrRev(wb.Name, ".", , 1)))
```

wb.name can later be replaced by the cells holding the path (by WB.WS.Cells(x, y).Value)